# What does MatConvNet do with Batch Normalization during testing and inference?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, batch-normalization

I was reading the documentation for [evaluating a simple CNN](http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/mfiles/simplenn/vl_simplenn/) and it said:

> In test mode, dropout and batch-normalization are bypassed. Note that,
>   when a network is deployed, it may be preferable to remove such blocks
>   altogether.

where it suggests to remove a batch normalization layer during training (lets ignore drop out because that is not relevant).

This seems very strange to me and I've grown a bit skeptical of this.

The reason for this is that [the original paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167v3.pdf) (1) says:

> The normalization of activations that depends on the mini-batch allows
>   efficient training, but is neither necessary nor desirable during
>   **inference**; we want the output to depend only on the input,
>   deterministically. For this, once the network has been trained, we use
>   the normalization $$\hat{x} = \frac{x - E[x]}{ \sqrt{Var[x] + \epsilon}}$$ using the **population**,
>   rather than mini-batch, statistics.

Which clearly seems to me that batch normalization still produces normalized activations $\hat{x}_i$ during inference, except that uses the population statistics $\mu$, $\sigma$ instead of mini batch estimates.

Furthermore, at the end of the pseudocode on the paper they suggest to replace the batch normalization transform with:

$$ y^{(k)} = \frac{\gamma^{(k)}}{\sqrt{Var[x] + \epsilon}} \hat{x}^{(k)} + \left( \beta^{(k)} - \frac{\gamma^{(k)} E[x]}{\sqrt{Var[x] + \epsilon }} \right)$$

with these two suggestions in the original paper I've grown very skeptical that following what MatConvNet suggests is a reasonable thing to do. Furthermore, if the network is trained using the BN layers, it seems that the **all** parameters **are trained assuming those layers are part of the network**, which intuitively, seems like a bad suggestion to remove the layers all together during inference or testing. Is that what MatConvNet suggests? Or do I have a misunderstanding? How exactly should one use Batch Normalization with MatConvNet?

---

[1](http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/mfiles/simplenn/vl_simplenn/): Ioffe S. and Szegedy C. (2015),
"Batch Normalization: Accelerating Deep Network Training by Reducing
Internal Covariate Shift",
*Proceedings of the 32nd International Conference on Machine Learning*, Lille, France, 2015.
Journal of Machine Learning Research: W&CP volume 37

Answer (score 1):

What is meant by a batch normalisation being bypassed is that it does not normalise the activations by batch statistics.

In the newer versions (since beta-18 I believe), the population statistics are computed during training as another parameter and then used during test time (e.g. see documentation [here](https://github.com/vlfeat/matconvnet/blob/master/matlab/vl_nnbnorm.m#L38) and [here](https://github.com/vlfeat/matconvnet/blob/master/matlab/simplenn/vl_simplenn.m#L148)).

What is meant by removing the batch-normalisation is to apply the additive and multiplicative constants to the closest convolution layer. You can see the way how it can be done in the [cnn-imagenet-deploy](https://github.com/vlfeat/matconvnet/blob/master/examples/imagenet/cnn_imagenet_deploy.m#L176) script in examples for imagenet.

Sorry for the misunderstanding. We will update the documentation to make it more clear.

Comment: So does this mean that during validation and testing stage we just need to set the 'Mode' option in vl_simplenn to 'test' and everything will work normally? Currently for Cifar-100, the training error for my network is down to 70% after 3 epochs but the validation error keeps staying at 99% for all batches. Seems like something isn't quite right...